# How to add attributes to changed background image in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: images, html, javascript

I'm trying to figure out how I can make a function that allows a user to set their own background image in my website via image URL that they enter. At first this was my code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="funcBgImage()"><img src="example.com/example-image-url.png" height=50, width=50></img></a>


<script>
function funcBgImage() {
var imageurl = prompt("Enter Image URL",
"");
            if (imageurl != null) { 
            document.body.style.background = "url('" + imageurl + "')"
}


}
</script>
```

And it works! But here's the problem:

*Every time* you set the image as anything too big or too small, it will simply repeat itself and not center itself and not resize itself at all. I tried fixing it with this code:

```
            if (imageurl != null) { 
            document.body.style.background = "url('" + imageurl + "');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;"
```

But this made the code not set a background at all, so it didn't work.

Any help? I really need to get this figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code and find some issues. Whenever you give style using javaScript, in that case you have to write document.body.style and then your attribute. By this, you can add multiple styles. You can use following code to and it works!

```
<a href="#" onclick="funcBgImage()"><img src="example.com/example-image-url.png" height=500, width=500></img></a>
<script>
    function funcBgImage() {
        var imageurl = prompt("Enter Image URL", "");
        if (imageurl != null) {
            document.body.style.background = "url('" + imageurl + "')";
            document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
            document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
        }
    }
</script>
```